# How to clean target directory before downloading artifact into it?

Tags: azure-pipelines

We ran into an issue where the same script used to deploy locally was giving unexpected behavior on remote server. After lot of debugging we found that this is because the [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#download) step in our Azure Pipeline:

```
steps:
  - download: current
```

does not *overwrite* the target directory i.e., any files left behind from previous runs will remain there and can cause unintended side-effects. Is there any way to tell the Azure pipeline to clean the target directory and remove everything in it before downloading the artifact?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How to clean target directory before downloading artifact into it?

You could set clean the workspace by following syntax:

```
jobs:
- job: string  # name of the job (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  ...
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job runs
```

You could this document [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#workspace) for some details.

Comment: thanks. confirmed this works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#schema

Comment: I want to add that this helped me as well. I had the same issue, and this worked.

Comment: I have three stages but only one of them just started having this issue with multiple artifacts in this folder. This fixed it. I guess I will add to other stages if this ever arbitrarily happens there.