# Why is my Azure DevOps pipeline outputting files to the server that doesn't exist in the published artifact?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have a .NET Core 8.0 web app which has both an `appsettings.json` file and an `appsettings.Test.json` file. I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that builds and deploys the app to a server. We are migrating away from using the `appsettings.Test.json` file and instead injecting environment variables into the `appsettings.json` file via the pipeline. How do I prevent the `appsettings.Test.json` file that is still in the repo (and will stay there for a little while until we've finished migrating and verified all functionality) from being outputed to the server?

The file in question is not visible in the published artifact.
[image: Image depicting an artifact where only appsettings.json can be seen in the file list]

But it ends up on the server anyway and it reappears after each pipeline run even if I have deleted it manually:
[image: Image depicting a file list where both appsettings.json and appsettings.Test.json can be seen]

I have tried adding the following in our `.csproj` file in different combinations but nothing seems to work. Based on what is said here: [ASP.NET Core: Exclude or include files on publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712055/asp-net-core-exclude-or-include-files-on-publish)

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.*.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.*.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.*.json" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My Pipeline looks like this:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - test
  paths:
   exclude:
     - src/ETLService/*

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  solution: '**/WebHost.sln'
  packageFolderName: 'WebHost'
  artifactName: 'WebAPI'
  IISWebsiteName: 'API'

stages: 
  - stage: BuildAndTest
    displayName: 'Build and test'
    jobs:
      - job: 
        displayName: '${{ variables.artifactName }}'
        steps:
            - template: PipelineTemplates/BuildAndTest.yml
            - template: PipelineTemplates/PublishWebArtifact.yml
  - stage: DeployToTest
    displayName: 'Deploy to test'
    variables:
    - group: APITest
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployAPI
        displayName: 'API'
        environment: 'Test.TEST-SERVER'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: none
                - download: 'current'
                  name: 'DownloadBuildArtifacts'
                  displayName: 'Download build artifacts'
                  artifact: '${{ variables.artifactName }}'
                - template: PipelineTemplates/DeployToIIS.yml
```

`BuildAndTest.yml`

```
steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: "Nuget install"
    
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: "Nuget restore"
    inputs:
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
      
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Dotnet build'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(solution)'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Dotnet test'
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(solution)'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

`PublishWebArtifact.yml`

```
steps:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Dotnet Publish"
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: false

  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: "Publish Web Artifact"
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      ArtifactName: '$(artifactName)'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

`DeployToIIS.yml`

```
steps:
  - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
    name: 'StopIIS'
    displayName: 'Stop IIS website'
    inputs:
      IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
      ActionIISWebsite: 'StopWebsite'
      StartStopWebsiteName: '$(IISWebsiteName)'
  - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
    inputs:
      WebSiteName: '$(IISWebsiteName)'
      Package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(artifactName)\$(packageFolderName)'
      TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
      JSONFiles: 'appsettings.json'
  - task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
    name: 'StartIIS'
    displayName: 'Start IIS website'
    inputs:
      IISDeploymentType: 'IISWebsite'
      ActionIISWebsite: 'StartWebsite'
      StartStopWebsiteName: '$(IISWebsiteName)'
```

Comment: If it's not part of the build artifacts, I'd guess that it already exists on the server and the deployment is not deleting existing files. There is a flag for it in Azure App Service deployment, can't remember how it went with IIS.

Comment: I have manually deleted the file on the server multiple times but after each pipeline run it reappears. There is such a flag you descibe for IIS deployment too, but I am reluctant to try it since someone decided to keep the log-folder inside the app-folder we publish to, and I don't want to erase the logs by mistake.

Comment: Hi, can you check the log of 'DownloadBuildArtifacts' task? It will show how many files are downloaded and the file names. If the `appsettings.Test.json` file is not downloaded in the task,  it means the file is generated after the task.. In addition, you can also check the contents of this file to see if you can get a hint as to where this file comes from.

Comment: I checked the log and the file is not listed. So either I am not deploying the same thing that is downloaded or it is added after the fact somehow. I am inclined to think I am deploying something else than I download. I deploy from this path `'$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(artifactName)\$(packageFolderName)'`. Is that not the downloaded artifact I get? (I download specified with `current` in the Deployment task. Does that end up somewhere else?

Comment: I tested in my pipeline and the `- download: 'current'` will download the artifacts to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)\$(artifactName)` folder. It is correct. Maybe you can add a command line task with `dir ` command to list the files in the folder before and after you deploy the app. In this way we can check if the file is in the folder.

Comment: I have come part way in figuring this out. For now I manage to not get the files in my output. I've tried a bunch of stuff and have gotten errors and tried different file paths and now noticed that the succeeded deploy I just got was correct, it did not have the unwanted file. I'll do some more testing and post an answer to my question with what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a typical case of wrongful assumptions. There was nothing wrong with my publishing of the artifact or my path-references deploying it. I had assumed that when I run a pipeline the agent working on it has a clean working directory to start with. This is not the case, and I never double checked this until I finally stumled over this post: [How to clean target directory before downloading artifact into it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391612/how-to-clean-target-directory-before-downloading-artifact-into-it)

So in my `$(Pipeline.Workspace)` folder I had remnants from a previous run where the files WERE outputted, and those versions were never cleaned out and kept being deployed. Unfortunately they got new timestamps on the target server every time so I thought they were newly generated just like the rest of the files.

The solution was to add the clean parameter in my deployment task in the pipeline:

```
- deployment: DeployAPI
  displayName: 'API'
  environment: 'Test.TEST-SERVER'
  workspace: # Added
    clean: all # Added
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer! If using a self-hosted agent, we can use the workspace clean options to clean the deployment workspace. When using Microsoft Hosted agent, since it is a new agent every time, there is no need to use this clean workspace.